# Passing an integer variable into an MySql select statement

Tags: mysql

I'm puzzle about how MySql handle the data in the select statement considering the following scenario.

1. selecting user with normal SQL statement

   select * from users where userid = 15;
2. select user with single quote around the integer values

   select * from users where userid = '15';

in both cases, MySql return same result so is there any difference between single quote integer and normal integer in MySql.
Is it safe to use quotes around the integer values?

Comment: Here's something to think about: Select 15 = '15test'

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (I don't rember the position exactly), it is better to use the integer variant.

It is outside of the scope of the question, buit it cannot be stressed enough: if you insert an arbitrary integer here, don't forget to make the query injection-safe. The best way to do so is to use prepared statements and to prepare the statement as `select * from users where userid = ?` and then set the parameter 1 of the statement to the integer value 15. How to do so exactly depends on the MySQL frameqork you use.

Comment: Please check this link,it may you                                              https://www.sigmainfy.com/blog/sql-single-quotes-for-numeric-values-is-it-really-good-practice.html

Comment: @Madhura this is what I want to know. Thanks for the link.